# tracker-extract 's cpu usage is HIGH?

Tags: 16.04, cpu-load, heat

Yesterday My CPU fan was making loud noise.I checked that fwupd was using 100% CPU. 
I followed the steps given [here](https://github.com/hughsie/fwupd/issues/70).

> I had the same problem and it can be an apt-get cache problem so it's recommended to clean the cache :

```
sudo -ic
apt-get clean
cd /var/lib/apt
mv lists lists.old
mkdir -p lists/partial
apt-get clean
apt-get update
```

or it can be a permission problem

```
sudo chown {user} /home/{user}/.cache/dconf
```

In addition I performed:

> sudo apt upgrade

And now getting new issue. This tracker-extract's CPU usage is high .
What to do, my Dell inspiron is getting heated up ?

[tracker-extract cpu usage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HDzHl.png)